# PHP - Send an e-mail with a delay of x time

Tags: javascript, php, email

I need send and email after x time using a php code.

I don't want use cronjob. so, this code doesn't works because the php code it's print one time and doesn't change the DOM automatically like js. But I need something like this:

```
  $today = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
  $dataorder = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $order->created);
  $delay_days = 240;
  $senday = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime( "$dataorder + $delay_days min" ));

   if ($today == $senday) {

    echo "sent";

   } else {

    echo "not yet sent";

   }
```

Now, I can use js, but I'm not sure if this will work, this php script is an all php page in the backend. so, can I use only php? like use sleep function? or other one

I don't know with is the best way.

(Specifically it is a system of sending emails to remember to leave a commend on the site.)

Thank you

Comment: It's going to be very difficult to achieve something like this without a task scheduler like cronjob.

Comment: really there is no other way to send a delayed email? use sleep could work? or time_sleep_until. I try to use it but at moment without success. I don't really know it!

Comment: @MarcoRomano You want a program to sleep for 240 days ? That would kill your server. 
You'll have to use a cron job or some other way of scheduling it. There is no other way out. Save the task to a database, and then have the cron job pick the tasks from it.

Comment: @BrahmaDev was 240 minutes just for test it. Will be 5 days. Anyway I guess it's the same. The problem is that with the cronjob I can send the email one day a week, but this will sends the emails to users in the same day. I need send emails at a distance of 5 days from the user's registration.

Comment: you are just trying to clone the cron functionalities in PHP. An unnecessary set of complications for no evident reasons. You can run a cron every x time and check what email are to be sent. Easy and straightforward

Comment: @LelioFaieta thank you. so I don't know how do, but ok I will go to study cron look like there is only this way!

Comment: Cron will run a php script each N seconds. Create the script to check emails to be sent and then schedule it to be run on a given interval. Note: cron is a linux o/s feature and not a PHP feature...

Comment: @MarcoRomano You can schedule cron to run every minute or once a year. Try some online cron tool for a better understanding like [crontab.guru](https://crontab.guru)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this as,

1. As you have data of user\'s you know on which date a particular user is registered.
2. Write a script which will execute every day & will select all the user's registered 5 days ago. Mail will be sent to all the user's matched for that date.
3. Script will continue to execute till last user is processed for that date.

Comment: I have the date of user registration. so, I can filter the user before the cronjob send the email, do you mean this?. This could be interesting.

Comment: @MarcoRomano yes...this way only the user's which are registered 5-day ago will be selected.